# Delete a UITableView row by click on custom UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Basically I want to delete row on click event of a button which is a part of that row.
I can not use commit editing style because i want to perform unsubscribe and delete with same button.
[image]

On click on subscribe button i want to delete that particular row.
so any idea, how can i do it.

Comment: You can always mark the solution that helped you most as the correct answer (the checkmark under the points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with following code

On button click event

```
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.table];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    [self.arraylist removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 2):

a. Add the target and callback to the button (I presume you already did that)

b. In the callback function, loop over the superviews to find the UITableViewCell and then find the index of it, like so:

```
-(void)deleteButtonPressed:(UIButton*)button {
    UIView* candidate = button;
    while (![candidate isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        candidate = candidate.superview;
    }
    NSIndexPath* indexPathToDelete = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    ...
```

c. Update your model first (very important)

```
[self.dataArrayThatFeedsTableView removeObjectAtIndex:indexPathToDelete.item]
```

d. Call the delete row

```
[self.tableView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathToDelete]];
```

Comment: Nice way to get the `UITableViewCell` reference! But, don't you think that this is an overkill? Just sayin' :)

Comment: In my projects, buttons are sometimes nested deep in the view so rather than assuming it is 2 or 3 levels up it is better to have a utility function that just returns the cell for any subchildren. It also looks better than button.superview.superview.superview ;-)

Comment: Consider using recursion!

Comment: 'removeObjectAtIndex' gives index beyond bound

Comment: @codingVoldemort You could definitely do that (recursion) as well although I do not consider it better or worst. Remember that in C, recursion was sometimes optimised internally as a while loop anyway!

Answer (score 1):

When you create row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` assign an indexPath.row to the button's tag, good idea is to add some number to avoid confusion with others button, for example:

```
cell.deleteButton.tag = 100 + indexPath.row
```

when the button is clicked cast the sender to the button, restore the button's tag (remember to subtract 100) and you know which row you want to remove.

Comment: @Bhavin what do you mean by won't work? Can you post the code?

Comment: i mean to say. i got a tag ok, now with this tag, how to delete this cell.

Comment: Just make sure you created indexPath from the button tag, print out the tag value to make sure it's right and you have to remove the object from your data source as well.

Comment: i logged the tag value and it's right because my subscribe facility works on every index..

Comment: Do you remove object from data source? can you post all the code you have to remove the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the button clicked in order to find the indexPath and from there find the cell that has that button:

```
var position: CGPoint =  sender.locationInView(self.tableView)
var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position)!    
var cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `indexPath` of the button that was tapped. And then delete the selected index paths using standard API call. Like so:

```
- (IBAction) didTapSubscribeButton:(UIButton*)sender {
     UIView* candidate = button;
     while (![candidate isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        candidate = candidate.superview;
    }
    NSIndexPath* indexPathToDelete = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:candidate];
     [self.dataSourceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row] //Considering that this is a single data source table view.
     NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@[indexPath],nil];
     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
     tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     [self.tableView endUpdates];
   }
```

Comment: [UIButton locationInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Edited with all due respect to @Mike's `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

Make a sub class of UIButton as CellButton with taking custom property like this

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```

set the custom class property for your button as the new one created and in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.btnSubscribe.indexPath=indexPath;
[cell.btnSubscribe addTarget:self action:@selector(subscribe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

now in the function

```
-(IBAction)subscribe:(id)sender{
    CellButton *button=(CellButton *)sender;
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:button.indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

give a try to this answer. am sure this will work

Answer (score -1):

Tapping a row and deleting it should be possible in a way like this:
In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can implement the following:

```
[myArrayWithSubscriptions removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

If you want to only tap the UIButton to delete use this code in the action behing the UIButton.

```
CGPoint point;
NSIndexPath *indexPath;
point = [sender.center locationInView:tableView];
indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
[myArrayWithSubscriptions removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

That way you have the indexPath from the cell that had its UIButton tapped, and should be able to continue to delete it.
I'm typing this on the go and will check this code later for any typos.

Comment: Clicking a button within the cell won't call `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @codingVoldemort I would like to ask you to reread my answer. I never said tapping a button will do that. Read: Tapping a row and deleting it should be possible in a way like this... I said row. Afterwards I even included a solution for tapping the button. The down vote is not nice...