# .deleteRows index issues swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview

[Here's a video of the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV1MlRIyrg8&feature=youtu.be)

I've been trying for weeks to find a solution yet can't find any... I can get it to work with .reloadData() but I don't want to use since it has to reload everything.

Heres the code when I click on a button the cell:

```
cell.hideAction = { (cell) in

            //....

            if self.Feed_ID.count == 1 {
                self.end_Feed()
            } else {

                //remove necessary data
                self.Feed_Body.remove(at: index)
                self.Feed_ID.remove(at: index)
                self.Feed_Group.remove(at: index)
                self.Feed_Date.remove(at: index)
                self.Feed_Report.remove(at: index)
                self.Feed_Votes.remove(at: index)
                self.Feed_user.remove(at: index)
                self.Feed_Owner.remove(at: index)
                self.Feed_App.remove(at: index)
                self.Feed_Contact.remove(at: index)

                let delPath = IndexPath(item: indexPath.row, section: 0)
                //tableView.deleteRows(at: [delPath], with: .left) works but displaces images
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [delPath], with: .left)

            }

        }
```

I also found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692747/delete-row-uitableview-index-issue) with no answer

Thank you!!

Comment: My *guess* would be that the value of `index` is captured when creating the cell, and therefore not correct when a preceding row has been deleted. – There are lots of solutions around to determine the actual table view row number from within a button action, this is the first one that I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504421/getting-row-of-uitableview-cell-on-button-press

Comment: You saved my life!! haha. Thank you so much!